# Excel showing dates including a greater than in the date filter column

Tags: excel

I have an excel pivotchart that is displaying a date as > 01/26/2020 and excluding all my values for Jan.  Anything prior to Jan is fine.  How can I fix this?

So I have 31 Dec 2021 and under that it says > 01/26/2020.  It does not display my Jan values.  Only the > 01/26/2020

Comment: Have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check the format of yours cells with **text to columns**:

1. Select the cell or column that contains the text you want to split.
2. Select Data > Text to Columns.
3. In the Convert Text to Columns Wizard, select Delimited > Next.
4. Select Next
5. Select the Column data format or use what Excel chose for you. **In your case date (GMA)**.
6. Select the Destination, which is where you want the split data to appear on your worksheet.
7. Select Finish.

Comment: I haven't but all the other dates are fine, I can't see how this would rectify the problem.

Comment: I suppose that your problem is a format-problem. If you want to sort the dates in column, or change their format, the text dates have to be converted to date with text to columns. Sometimes I got the same problem and I solved it by converting all data in a column with **text to columns**.